# php foreach div class issue

Tags: php, foreach, key, foreach-loop-container

I have some php code below, where I'm using foreach.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php if(count($items)): ?>
    <?php foreach($items as $key=>$item) : ?>      
      <div class="item <?php echo ($key%2) ? "active" : ""; ?>">
        <?php
                $extra_imagefilename = md5("Image".$item->id);
                $extra_imagepath = 'media/k2/items/src/'.$extra_imagefilename.'.jpg';
                preg_match_all('/img src="([^"]+)"/i', $item->introtext . $item->fulltext, $matches); ?>
                <?php if(@file_exists($extra_imagepath)) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $extra_imagepath; ?>" style="alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" />
                <?php } ?>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>                         
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

I need the 1st div that appears to have a class called "item active" and all other div classes in the foreach to have a class of "item".

Where have I gone wrong with the below code?

```
  <?php if(count($items)): ?>
    <?php foreach($items as $key=>$item) : ?>      
      <div class="item <?php echo ($key%2) ? "active" : ""; ?>">
```

Any help/advice would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What values does `$key` have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`($key%2) ? "active" : "";` will output `active` for any `$key` that is not divisible by 2. See Wikipedia's page about the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Assuming you use numeric indexes for `$item` and they are consecutive starting with `0` you can just write

```
<div class="item <?php echo ($key == 0) ? "active" : ""; ?>">
```

to have the first `div` have the `class` active.

If you don't know about the values of `$key` you could just use a flag:

```
<?php $first = true; foreach($items as $key=>$item) : ?>      
    <div class="item <?php if ($first){echo "active"; $first = false;} ?>">
```

On the first run `$first` will be `true` and your `div` gets it's class `active`. On any other run it will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reset function as a check.

```
<?php if(count($items)): ?>
  <?php foreach($items as $key=>$item) : ?>      
    <div class="item <?php echo ($item==reset($items) ? "active" : ")"; ?>">
```

Comment: Do not do this if you have any particular need to not have infinite loops in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`$key%2` is every odd  value of $key but I think the condition will always evaluate to true. Use  `($key ==0)? "active" : ""`   to get only the first one active.